# How to correctly connect op-amp to ADC

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, photodiode

I have a SiPM connected to an op amp and then ADC.  Everything works great except I am just guessing at what values to choose for R2 and C1.  What questions should I be answering in choosing the aforementioned components?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqaIxu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: that's an *RC low pass filter*, so it's easy to find out using google what values you'd need for a specific cut-off frequency. Since that filter is used as anti-aliasing filter, it's up to whoever is using the ADC to set the frequency it needs to cut off – it depends on your sampling rate and the bandwidth of your signal of interest.

Comment: @Toby Jackson: if the (+)-terminal of a -27V voltage source is connected to GND the (-)-terminal is +27V **above** GND, i.e. your photo diode is forward biased. I guess that's not what you've meant. So either turn the voltage source or label it +27V.

Answer (score 4):

The series R / shunt C serves as both an *anti-aliasing filter* and also a *charge reservoir* for the track/hold. This type of A/D converter (SAR or Successive Approximation Register) has an internal switched-capacitor array which is periodically connected to the input pin, to sample the input voltage. Right at the moment it begins tracking the input, there is a disruption as the internal sampling capacitor is not at the same voltage as the input. As long as it reaches the correct voltage before the tracking interval ends, all is well; but a high-impedance source may have trouble with accuracy. This is explained in the 
[Maxim Integrated MAX153 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX153.pdf):

> page 10
>   Input Current
>   Figure 8 shows the equivalent circuit of the
>   converter input. When the conversion starts and WR is low, VIN is
>   connected to 16 0.6pF capacitors. During this acquisition phase, the
>   input capacitors charge to the input voltage through the resistance of
>   the internal analog switches (about 2kOhm). In addition, about 12pF of
>   stray capacitance must be charged. The input can be modeled as an
>   equivalent RC network (Figure 9). As source impedance increases, the
>   capacitors take longer to charge. The typical 22pF input capacitance
>   allows source resistance as high as 2.2kOhm without setup problems.
>   For larger resistances, the acquisition time (tP) must be increased.

So there are several design constraints you need to meet:

- sensor source impedance
- charge reservoir set by SAR internal sampling array
- anti-aliasing cutoff frequency set by RC
- minimum acquisition time required for accuracy

The sensor source impedance is the equivalent Thevenin or Norton internal resistance of whatever you're trying to measure. If you had any choice you'd obviously want to select 0 impedance, but a practical sensor always has some impedance. Higher impedance means the signal will suffer more distortion, due to the ADC's input current. Anything over about 6000 ohms should be considered "high impedance". In your case you already have an op amp, which has a fairly low impedance output driver.

The C in the filter should be at least as large as the internal sampling capacitance. More external C means less disruption during the tracking interval. However too high C can also cause ringing, overshoot, or sluggish response.

An anti-aliasing filter is required because any input energy present with frequency > 1/2 sample rate, will still appear in the digitized input -- but there is no way to untangle the aliased frequencies from the fundamental frequencies. Generally the anti-aliasing RC cutoff should have reasonable attenuation at the Nyquist aliasing frequency limit. If there's likely to be a lot of extraneous signal above Nyquist limit, that's going to be more of a concern. If it's inside a quiet, shielded enclosure, you can probably get away with less aggressive filtering.

These constrains somewhat interact; sensor impedance affects the R, the SAR internal capacitance affects the C, and the product RC affects the corner frequency.

To be fair, the MAX153 is a really ancient part with very low resolution, but the same principles apply to any SAR type of ADC.

Answer (score 1):

This is the low-pass filter on the input of the IC. It ensures, that no unwanted high-speed noise or spikes go through to the ADC.

For the values, the resistor will limit the max current charging the capacitor. For example, when you have the capacitor fully discharged and a 1 ohm resistor, the peak current will equal to Vcc/1 ohm, since the capacitor acts as a short when fully dicharged and step voltage is applied. I usually put something between 1k and 10k, but it can differ for your circuit, you have to know max current capabilities of the opamp's output and/or circuit output.

Having the resistor value estimated, use [this calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRlowkeisan.htm) to calculate the cap. You need to know the frequency of the signal you will read. For example, a 10k res and 1n cap gives the cut-off frequency of 15.915 kHz, which means that a sinusoidial signal of that frequency will be 1.4 times smaller in amplitude. Look at the Bode diagram in the calculator and adjust the components so that your frequency is in the flat region on the left.